# Knit with R markdown

Tags: r, data, data-cleaning, data-analysis

I have tried running some code on RStudio Desktop, within the Chunk the codes runs smoothly, but when knitting to view as html, I get the message that something is wrong with a line of code. What can I do please.
[This is the code I wrote and I was okay][1]
But I got this error message while trying to view it in html

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Well, you need to debug ;) If you need help with that you should at least include the code causing the problem, we are not magicians! Also you could probably ask your question (wiith more details) on https://stackoverflow.com/, since it's a simple programming problem.

Comment: Please edit the question using the small "edit" link at the bottom of the question and copy your code in the main question. You should also add the error message and if relevant show a small sample of your data. The error message tells you which line in the code causes the problem, so please indicate this as well.

Comment: I used the code below (apologies I should have indicated that I am new to R programing). When I run the code it gives me result.                                                                                                                                        library(tidyverse)
left_join(data_set_1, data_set_2) %>% glimpse
When I try to knit the code to view what it looks like, I get this error message: error in left_join(data_set_1, data_set_2) : object "data_set_1" not found

Comment: I have edited the question and included the image of the codes I used.

Comment: Just for your information, showing code screenshots is [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7311767) on StackExchange, it's better to copy/paste the text itself. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message tells you that there is no variable `mcq_grade`. Most likely when you ran the code yourself you had already loaded some data from a file and assigned it to `mcq_grade`, it could look like this:

```
mcq_grade <- read.table(filename)
```

All the code that you put in your R markdown source document must be independent because it's executed in a new environment. Btw this is the goal: this way the code is reproducible independently from the environment.

This means that if some dataset must be loaded first, it must be loaded from the R markdown document itself. Mind that the R Markdown doc is executed in the directory where the source is located, so you might have to adjust the path to the file.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you